# Baseline a package and include out of package elements

Tags: enterprise-architect, baseline

I currently have a package that contains model diagrams only. These model diagrams include elements from a common library that other packages include in their diagrams. I want to avoid baselining the library package and diagram package separately since the library is very large.

What would be the best way to baseline the package with the model diagram to include all the elements in its diagram?

Comment: So what is your intention? Create a baseline of the elements referenced in the diagrams only and skip the unreferenced ones?

Comment: Ultimately yes, these packages only contain a few diagrams. The issue is that the elements in these diagrams belong in another package outside of the package I want to baseline.

Comment: Are you using a framework to organize your model? The answer would differ depending on how you organize your library. Personally, i think its best you baseline the diagram package and the library package, more so if anything can make it to your diagram.

Comment: That is the method we are using right now. But in the case we will want to roll back to a previous diagram baseline (with elements in that previous snapshot), the library package will be rolled back - in which case some unrelated elements in that library would also be rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I made was a VBS script to read the diagrams in the specific package for all elements and bring them into the package to baseline, it will then baseline the package. After baselining, it returns those elements to their original parent packages.

Comment: Do you have any measure what the overhead of that is? Also: what happens when you restore such a baseline and the moved elements are not where you temporarily baselined them?

Comment: I'm not sure what measure to say for the overhead, but it runs within seconds for our model. For the case you mentioned, EA will update the entire model so if there is an element that isn't in the package of the  the temporary baseline is, EA will move the element to the baselined package automatically when restoring.